# Dynamic Mapping Table To Model Entity Framework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am looking for a way to dynamically map a model to a table based on the url of the deployed application. The table name it needs to map to will get its prefix from a part of the url. So far I have only found a way to map the tables once on startup by overriding the OnModelCreating method. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  `OnModelCreating` runs once per DbContext type *by default*, but you can replace that behavior with something custom.

You just need to provide your own `IModelCacheKeyFactory`.  Documented here: [Alternating between multiple models with the same DbContext type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/dynamic-model)